# Break disappear while debugging C in Netbeans

Tags: c, compiler-errors

everybody.

I have installed gdb (throw cygwin) on my Windows 8 machine with NetBeans 7.3.

As the title said my problem is that the breakpoints just disappear when I run the debug ( to reappear as soon as it finished), so basically I have a normal run.

Any ideas how to fix that, the tutorial on the Netbeans page doesn't really help, and I have found a solution with a special flag [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201670) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compiled your code with optimizer flags, then the line may not exist. When debugging, compile your code with `-g` and remove `-O`